# Need help understand the message from upgrading Django

Tags: django

Can someone help me understand what I need to do in response to this error message--or whether anything needs to be done at all? This happened when I decided to upgrade Django from 3.1x to 3.2 (no need to delve into the reasons--a learner's mistakes).

I followed the official instructions to test for dependency issues, `$ python -Wa manage.py test`, and nothing showed up. Then `python -m pip install -U Django` yielded the following long message. The last line declares `Successfully installed Django-3.2 asgiref-3.3.4`, but why the long message.

```
python3 -m pip install -U Django

WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Requirement already satisfied: Django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.1.7)
Collecting Django
  Using cached Django-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Django) (0.4.1)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.3.2
  Using cached asgiref-3.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Django) (2020.5)
Installing collected packages: asgiref, Django
  Attempting uninstall: asgiref
    Found existing installation: asgiref 3.3.1
    Uninstalling asgiref-3.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled asgiref-3.3.1
  Attempting uninstall: Django
    Found existing installation: Django 3.1.7
    Uninstalling Django-3.1.7:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-3.1.7
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/UNKNOWN
sysconfig: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Successfully installed Django-3.2 asgiref-3.3.4
```

Comment: You can follow the github link in the warning. There is an explanation of the reason available.

Comment: @Razenstein I saw "GitHub" in the warning, but is the message about git and GitHub? I makes sense because that's where the mess started. The "user", "home" reference threw me off.

Comment: @Razenstein It does seem to relate to GitHub issues (I clicked on the link and checked). Thank you!!!